# Functional programming function confusion

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml

I'm learning functional programming and am using Ocaml, but I'm having a bit of a problem with functions.

Anyway, I have a tuple and I want to return its first value. (Very simple I know, sorry)

```
let bach (x,y):(float*float) = (x,y);;
val bach : float * float -> float * float = <fun>
```

All well and good up here.

```
let john (x,y):(float*float) = y;;
val john : 'a * (float * float) -> float * float = <fun>
```

Now this is what confuses me. Why is there a `'a` there? I know that it stands for a variable with an unknown type, but I'm confused as to how changing the return value adds that there.

I am a self professed n00b in functional programming, please don't eat me :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You were bitten by a subtle syntax mistake that is really non-obvious for beginners:

```
 let foo x : t = bar
```

is not the same as

```
 let foo (x : t) = bar
```

it is on the contrary equivalent to

```
 let foo x = (bar : t)
```

constraining the return type of the function.

.

So you have written

```
let john (x, y) = (y : float * float)
```

The input type is a pair whose second element, `y`, has type `float * float`. But `x` can be of any type, so the function is *polymorphic* in its type, which it represents as a type variable `'a`. The type of the whole function, `'a * (float * float) -> float * float`, indicates that for any type `'a`, you may pass a tuple of an `'a` and a `(float * float)`, and it will return a `(float * float)`.

This is a particular case of the `snd` function:

```
let snd (x, y) = y
```

which has type `'a * 'b -> 'b`: for any `'a` and `'b`, you take a pair `('a * 'b)` and return a value of type `'b`.

Answer (score 1):

In both of your examples you are giving type-constraints for the result of the defined function, instead of its argument (as was probably intended).

Thus

```
let john (x, y) : (float * float) = y;;
```

means that the result of `john` (i.e., `y`) should be of type `(float * float)`. Now, since in the input we have a pair consisting of `x` (of which nothing is known) and `y` (of type `float * float`), the final type for the input is `'a * (float * flat)`.

To get what you want, you could use:

```
let john ((x:float), (y:float)) = y;;
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to learn Ocaml and functional programming in general, [Programming Languages](https://www.coursera.org/course/proglang) course is going to be offered at Coursera again. You will learn programming language concepts by SML, Racket and Ruby and have fun assignments to apply what you learn. Highly recommended.